# Visual Studio 2019 python workspace settings

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2019

I've been getting an unresolved import error for my modules on python django. I searched online for a solution however I  only found a solution that works on VSCode which is to add into the workspace/settings.json file

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["\\project-path"].
```

This solution does not work for visual studio 2019 just like how adding into the workspace PythonSettings.json

```
"python.pythonPath": "project\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe
```

does not work and only works if you add

```
"Interpreter":"project\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe
```

Is there a way to add extraPath into VS 2019 or another way?